# Twilio Recording returning negative duration value "-1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I am  facing an issue regarding the recording duration just after the call is ended.
Once the call is completed we are finding the recording and getting the duration but we are recieving  the r.duration in the below snippet in negative value i.e "-1" instead returning the duration in seconds format.

```
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(TWILIO["ACCOUNT_SID"],TWILIO["ACCOUNT_TOKEN"])
call = client.account.calls.get(call_sid)
if call.present?
  call.recordings.list.each do |r|
  consultation_duration = (r.duration.to_i/60).to_f
  #downloading the recording logic
  r.delete
  end
end
```

Can anyone please let me know what is the reason which causing Twilio returning negative duration.

Comment: I would recommend getting in touch with Twilio help so that this can be looked at in more detail. Just email them at help@twilio.com and they'll get back to you.

Comment: Can we see `r.inspect`?

Comment: I doubt that, because `r` is an entire recording object.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think it's because you are dividing that number by 60 when it's already in seconds. You could change your code to the following and it would give you the [`duration`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance-properties) in seconds anyway.

```
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(TWILIO["ACCOUNT_SID"],TWILIO["ACCOUNT_TOKEN"])
call = client.account.calls.get(call_sid)
if call.present?
  call.recordings.list.each do |r|
  consultation_duration = r.duration
  #downloading the recording logic
  r.delete
  end
end
```

To explain a bit if the call lasted for 30 seconds, you'd be dividing it by 60 which is probably then giving you the behavior you're seeing after casting it.

If you wanted to convert to something like HH:MM:SS for example, you could change your code to do the following:

```
t = 33 # seconds
Time.at(t).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

And this would give you a nicely formatted time like this:

> 00:00:33

Hope this helps you

Comment: Why would dividing by 60 produce a negative number if the original number were positive? Even with integer division, `30/60 == 0`.

Comment: I also would have thought it should give you 0, but testing it here produced the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio returns negative duration for recordings not finished yet. It means call still in progress, and final duration not specified yet.